# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^n+1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have trouble with the following sum: $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^n+1}{n}$$

Since $a_n=\frac{2}{n}$ decreases monotonically and tends to $0$, it converges by Liebniz criterion.

Then, by Abel's theorem we have that $S$ converges **uniformly** for $|x| < 1$.

- Question 1. Is this correct?
- Question 2. How can I show that it diverges for $|x| > 1$? I've been unable to prove it with the usual tests.
- Question 3. How can I show that it doesn't converge absolutely in $(-1,1)$?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: For Question 2, note that the terms of the series do not approach zero when $|x|>1$.  Therefore the series diverges.  For Question 3, note that $|x^n+1|>1/2$ for $n$ some point on.

Answer (score 2):

First you can just focus on the series $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n}x^n$ since the series $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is convergent. Now this first series is an entire series and it's convergent on the interval $(-1,1]$.

Comment: Additionally, for $x \in (-1,1]$ we have $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}x^n=-\ln (1+x)$ and so $S=-\ln (1+x)-\ln 2$

Comment: Thanks user235783, but I'm afraid I'm still stuck with the original serie.